# WPMU - How to get blog link of current user?

Tags: wordpress, networking, dynamic

I am working on a wordpress network and I am trying to figure out how to create a if/else link that will take the current user from the main site to a specific page on their blog. For example in theory this is what I am trying to achieve  -

```
<?php global $wp_roles;
foreach ( $wp_roles->role_names as $role => $name ) :
if (current_user_can( $role ) && $role == 'HAS A BLOG') { ?>

<a href="<?php URL TO USERS BLOG ?>/SPECIFIC-PAGE/">A Page on your blog</a>

<?php } else {   ?>

<a href="HOME">MAIN SITE</a>
```

I found some info on something similar but I could not get it to work for me at all - [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46056/how-can-i-get-multisite-primary-blog-url-or-path-for-current-user)

How can I go about getting this to work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By using this code I am almost able to achieve what I want. For some reason though it is only echoing the main site. How can I modify this to make sure it echoes the current users site?`if(is_user_logged_in()) {
global $current_user;
  $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
     if($blogs) {
       foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
         echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'">' .  $blog->blogname . '</a></li>';
  }
     }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to achieve what I want by using the following code -

```
<?php if(current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
global $current_user;
  $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->id );
     if($blogs) {
         foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
if($blog->userblog_id != 1) { 
         echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'upload-and-manage-documents/">My Documents</a></li>';
         echo '<li><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'upload-and-manage-documents/?ptype=settings&tab=gateways">Settings</a></li>';
}
  }
}
}
 ?>
```